Flutter web scroll is not smooth on ios/iphone chrome and safari browser
project is working fine on windows, android, a bit sticky on mac book browsers and almost completely stuck on iPhone (13,15 plus),
In development mode, it works fine on the iPhone, but after building with Canvakit and deploying the project, the scroll is stuck on the iPhone.
Flutter 3.24.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5874a72aa4 (3 months ago) • 2024-08-20 16:46:00 -0500
Engine • revision c9b9d5780d
Tools • Dart 3.5.1 • DevTools 2.37.2


The issue seems to be related to the scrolling mechanism in Flutter Web when running on iOS browsers like Safari and Chrome. Here are some steps you can try to fix the issue:

Change the Renderer:
Make sure you are using the right graphics option in Flutter (like html instead of CanvasKit) to improve compatibility with iOS browsers.
Disable Overscroll:
iOS browsers add an Overscroll effect which can cause issues. You can adjust the scroll settings to disable this effect.
Test the production version:
Sometimes the issues are related to development mode only. Create a production version (flutter build web --release) and test it on your device.
Update the Flutter environment:
Make sure you are using the latest version of Flutter, as updates may contain improvements or fixes for this issue.
Check the performance:
If the issue is related to performance, you can reduce the graphics load through design improvements like reducing the use of complex graphics.

If the issue persists, please share more details about the settings you are using (such as browser type and version)

I tried CanvasKit, html renderer, Both have same issue.  Besides tried all your mentioned suggestion but nothing work

If you're using SingleChildScrollView(), it's not using lazy loading. Use ListView() instead. ListView will improve performance

I am already using Listview, so it does not work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
